# Changing Button Color in Wordpress mobile navbar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navbar, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to change the background color of the "Contact" button in the mobile navbar of this website https://originmedia.at  with Wordpress to the same orange color like the other buttons on the website. Does anyone know how I can change it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code to Customize > Additional CSS:

```
#menu-2-5279cfc li:last-child a {
   background: cornflowerblue;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: it worked:) how did u get this id "#menu-2-5279cfc" ?

Comment: I inspected the page source and got it from the unordered list for mobile menu

Comment: oh okay, thx... any idea how i can hover the orange play button on the landing page ? I tried it the same way, but only the border changes. Maybe because its an img of an button ?

Comment: Hi Which orange button in particular? There are a lot of orange buttons on the homepage.